# Spring boot data.sql does not initialize data in Postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Spring Rest Api application.
This is the **entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="a_example")
public class Example
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String filename;
}
```

Here is my **data.sql** in the resources folder:

```
INSERT INTO a_example(name, description, filename) VALUES('Xyz', 'Lorem ipsum', 'xyz');

INSERT INTO a_example(name, description, filename) VALUES('Pqr', 'Lorem ipsum', 'pqr');
```

And my **application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xyz
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

The table exists, I can add data other ways, but I would prefer the data.sql to initalize it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` should be `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`. Try adding this property as well `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to see if the sql is being triggered or not

Comment: the only thing that worked for me was this prop spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always which is deprecated by the way lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change  `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` in the `application.properties` file And Change `GeneratedValue` annotation in the `Example` entity as below:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

FYI: You can use Liquibase or Flyway libraries too.