# Is it possible to use data.sql without schema.sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to initialise schema using `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and then populate using data.sql.

I tried it but it doesn't seem to work without schema.sql. Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below config to your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

and use below config if you have data in the table:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886569/spring-boot-data-sql-does-not-initialize-data-in-postgresql/60888746#60888746) and its answer.

Comment: I tried it already. But data.sql is executed before the table is created so it fails

Comment: I think I will go with db migrations instead

Comment: Hi Nasir, I have understood the root problem. It was not that it was not getting executed. You definitely helped me understanding the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

will load your data.sql script after your table is generated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).